# Loader animation for C# desktop based application

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application, loader

Is there a way that similar in jquery ajax beforeSend and complete in C#?

Because in web I usually do when pressing like an add button i set `beforendSend:` a function to show an image and hide image function in `complete:`

And now I want to do in C# desktop application. Is there any similar to that? like some kind of using a progress bar

Comment: what are you wanting to show progress of?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a winforms application?  It has a ProgressBar control you can use. There is one for WPF as well.  But you will want to do your processing on a background thread so your UI remains responsive and updates your progress bar.

Comment: Winforms, how can I set the progressbar to run during execution of a function to determine the processing time of it or some thing similar. im not using WPF.

Comment: Have a look at the API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx  there are various ways to do it and there is an example there!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to perform background processing and UI callbacks. Very simple example below:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessingEvent += AnEventOccurred;

        ThreadStart threadStart = new ThreadStart(LongRunningProcess);
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadStart);
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void LongRunningProcess()
    {
        RaiseEvent("Start");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            RaiseEvent("Processing " + i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        if (ProcessingEvent != null)
        {
            ProcessingEvent("Complete");
        }
    }

    private void RaiseEvent(string whatOccurred)
    {
        if (ProcessingEvent != null)
        {
            ProcessingEvent(whatOccurred);
        }
    }

    private void AnEventOccurred(string whatOccurred)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Processing(AnEventOccurred), new object[] { whatOccurred });
        }
        else
        {
            this.label1.Text = whatOccurred;
        }
    }

    delegate void Processing(string whatOccurred);

    event Processing ProcessingEvent;
```

Comment: In my button I have a function named AddProducts() with sql insert queries on it. Where should I put the backgroundworker to start and it display the progress in progressbar when addProducts() function is done the progress bar completes ..

Comment: I would 1) refactor and put all product processing methods in a class/service, 2) definte the delegate and events on those service classes, 3) create and start the thread that executes the process methods of the service classes on the UI triggering events (button click, etc.), 4) define processing event handlers on UI classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement like below:

```
    FrmLoading f2 = new FrmLoading();   // Sample form whose Load event takes a long time
    using (new PleaseWait(this.Location, () => Fill("a")))  // Here you can pass method with parameters
          { f2.Show(); }
```

PleaseWait.cs

```
public class PleaseWait : IDisposable
{
    private FrmLoading mSplash;

    //public delegate double PrdMastSearch(string pMastType);
    public PleaseWait(Point location, Action methodWithParameters)
    {
        //mLocation = location;
        Thread t = new Thread(workerThread);
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
        methodWithParameters();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        mSplash.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(stopThread));
    }
    private void stopThread()
    {
        mSplash.Close();
    }
    private void workerThread()
    {
        mSplash = new FrmLoading();   // Substitute this with your own
        mSplash.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        //mSplash.Location = mLocation;
        mSplash.TopMost = true;
        Application.Run(mSplash);
    }
}
```

It works 100% correct ... now currently worked in my system.