# Accessing Form components through a threaded method in a plain old C# class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Before getting to the question let me provide a little background. First MyMainForm starts which does two things it initializes a form called Form2 and then calls a method in a different class passing that method an instance of Form2 as a parameter. This can be seen from the figure below. The method then runs a different method say `RunInThread` in a new thread. Now what I want to know is how I can change data on a textbox on form2 through the RunInThread Method.The Picture also explain my scenario. I tried creating a delegate to a method which changes the text in the textbox and that delegate was in Form2 Class however it seems that you cannot call that delegate from the RunInThread method. Any suggestions on how I could change the text in the Textbox of Form2 through RunInThread method.

[image]

Comment: Assuming this is winforms, it sounds like you need to have a look at the BeginInvoke (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.90).aspx) method.

Comment: I tried doing something like this but in a simple C# class not derived from the `Form` class the begininvoke method is non existent. In short you cant use `this.begininvoke` in `SomeMethod()`

Comment: see answer to related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390778/loader-animation-for-c-sharp-desktop-based-application/13391028#13391028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the method, RunInThread(Form2 frm_) do something like this:

```
frm_.BeginInvoke( new System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker( () => 
   { 
      frm_.myTextBox.Text = "Hey this updated!!"; 
   }));
```

This will cause the myTextBox.Text property setter to be called via the windows forms GUI thread that frm_ was created on.

Comment: I get the following Error `Error 2 - The type or namespace name 'MethodInvoker' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) in InterfaceImpl.CS` .

Comment: BTW the textbox is not available through the frm_ instance in this case

Comment: May I ask where the textbox is available from?

Comment: I adjusted the code to have the full namespace for MethodInvoker

Comment: So I did exactly as suggested but with a minor change. I cant seem to access myTextbox from the frm_ instance . I dont know why ? I hope you could tell me . Therefore I just created a public method called `UpdateTextBox(String str)` and called that method like `frm_.UpdateTextBox("Hey this updated")`

Comment: Ahh okay. I think I see. If you want to access the text box directly, go to the Windows Forms Designer for your form, select the control you want to make available, and then change the "Modifiers" property to "Public".

Comment: One last question why isnt the public delegate that I created inside the frm class available here ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19617/discussion-between-phil-martin-and-casper-2211)